# How to populate an array of groups from a many to many table that a user belongs to in cakePHP

Tags: mysql, arrays, cakephp

My cakePHP site has three tables; users, groups and groups_users.

users.id joins groups_users.users_id via a one to many relationship.

groups.id joins to groups_users.groups.id via a one to many relationship.

Therefore, groups_users contains a list of all users and the groups they are in. E.g user 1 might be in groups 1, 2 and 3. groups_users also contains a separate primary key field.

I want to be able to return an array of the group names (groups.groupName) that a user is a member of when they log in, and then keep this array and use it to check whether that groupName has permission to view specific pages of the site.

I'm new to cake, but comfortable with php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer a containable in these situations. I'm sure somebody will tell me if there's a reason to not do it this way.

First you need to add this line to your User model:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Make sure you have your relationships set up correctly here as well. Then you can use the following code in your controller.

```
$groups = $this->User->find('first', array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'User.id' => $id
  ),
  'contain' => array(
    'Group' => array(
       'fields' => array(
         'Group.groupName'
        )
      )
   )
));
$this->set('groups', $groups);
```

The last line makes the variable available in your views. Try running debug($groups) in either your controller or view to see the output.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help - i really appreciate it. I'm struggling a little though with an error related to the use of $this in my UsersController. Does your code need to be wrapped in a function? i've got it inside class UsersController at the moment...

Comment: This should be in a public function matching the name of your page  inside the controller class.